# Trailing edge dimmer

Tags: dimmer

After having a successful design with a leading edge dimmer, I want to design a trailing edge dimmer for 230 VAC LED bulb dimming.
However, I'm having design difficulties with the power supply for the MOSFETs. I'm powering my circuit from a 230 VAC to 5 VDC isolated PSU. However, to power the mosfets, they need a 15 V non isolated PSU.

To simplify things, I found an IC "ADUM6132" which has an integrated isolated boost converter. I'm unfamiliar with this, but is this the correct way of using this MOSFET driver? Or are there other good options?

[image]

Another, simpeler and cheaper option I found is by using a VOM1271 or TLP191B with this very simple circuit:

[image]

Comment: Your diode D2 appears to be reversed, and is probably unnecessary, as the VOM1271 outputs only about 9V open circuit. 53 uSec turn-on and 25 uSec turn-off might cause excessive power dissipation in the MOSFETs especially if gate capacitance is high. (as @Jens observed).

Answer (score 1):

The [datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADuM6132.pdf) shows an NPN/PNP buffer driving the MOSFET gates of a half-bridge, which will provide much better drive current and speed than your simple NPN with pull-up. It may not be critical if you are switching at power line frequency, but I would use the buffer shown. Actually, it might even be better to use the drive output directly - it has 200 mA capability.

Comment: With drive output directly; you mean driving it without transistor?

Comment: Yes, I don't see why that wouldn't work OK.

Answer (score 0):

Some words to your second circuit.
I like these photovoltaic solutions, they are useful for static load switching, but in this case I would not recommend it.

- In your circuit the MOSFET gates together have about 3 nF capacitance and the datasheet of the VOM1271 specifies a turn on time of 53 us at 200 pF load. So expect more than half a millisecond here. Turn off is longer as well.
- During this time the MOSFETs are partial conducting and dissipate a lot of power.
- This power loss may be acceptable for single switching events with enough time in between to cool down and if the SOA of the FET allows it, but here it applies for up to 10 % of the time. Calculate your thermal margin.
- You may get some kind of "over the edge" or "in between" dimmer. That may be OK for LEDs, but is bad style.
- If there is a shortcut on the load side, the question is: What trips first, fuse or semiconductor? It is not the fuse here.

Comment: I did draw the wrong MOSFETs in the schematic. I intend to use fcu360n, which have less capacity. Maybe there are better MOSFETs suitable for this? Why would a say 500ma fuse not trip?

Comment: A better one might be using APV1111GVY which comes in a bit more expensive but provide good specs

Comment: @jancoow APV1111 sounds promising with FCU360N, thanks for the hint. Well, 0.5AF may trip in time, try it ;)